# Need an example of a "Good Line of Business Application" for .NET that uses ORM

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, mvp

I'm trying to move toward TDD, ORM, Mocking, ect. I need a good example of a line of business app that uses an ORM preferably NHibernate.

It has to be open source and use the repository pattern.

I learn best by example, I have played around with the repository pattern and unit of work pattern but not in any meaningful applications.

I'm familiar with IoC (I use unity), WCF, Workflow Foundation, WPF, Smart Client Software Factory, Webclient Software Factory, ect.

I've learned all the "basics" (they are pretty advanced principals to be called basics, IMO) I just can't seem to put it all together.

The applications we write follow all "best practices" as far as architecture, we have a business logic layer, data access layer, MVP, MVVP, MVC, ect. but there is never any code in our BLL's besides

```
return dal.GetBlahBlahBlah();
```

I have to ask myself where is all my business logic???

Probably 95% of our data access is through stored procedures and I have to assume that its all if the database. Some of these SP's are huge and have lots and lots of if statements, case statement, and the occasional cursor.

As mentioned above I know how to use all of these cool technologies but it seems like the only thing I'm using them for is to make a really, really overcomplicated, overly architecture'd reporting tool for sql server.

If ALT.NET is the better way, if having all of your business logic in the code is the better way, there has to be an open source application out there that puts it all together in all the right ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't come across any LOB applications but I have heard that [Cuyahoa](http://www.cuyahoga-project.org/) is an excellent example of how to use NHibernate.

I am familiar with the code in [Suteki Shop](http://code.google.com/p/sutekishop/), an e-commerce platform using ASP.Net MVC and Linq-To-Sql which is active at the moment and being re-factored very well and should provide you with some insight in to what you're attempting.

Penultimately, there is Rob Conery's [MVC StoreFront](http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/). Rob is the master of screencasts and presents a great insight in to learning TDD.

My final link is [summer of nhibernate](http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/) another series of screencasts this time specifically on using NHibernate